# vb.net character detection from video and extract to image

Tags: .net, vb.net, opencv, emgucv, detection

example:

file name: test.mp4
file duration: 46min

program will start scan at 0 min to 46 min (frame by frame)
if there is a subtitle or text on video, capture that frame and extract to image

NOT OCR, JUST CAPTURE AND EXTRACT IMAGE

someone told me i can do it by opencv or emgucv
but i dont know how to do it.. so, can you guys give me tutorial?

original image
[image]

image after extract
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a video stream in Emgucv, and capture a frame that you want.

```
private List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> GetVideoFrames(String Filename)
{
        List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> image_array = new List<Image<Bgr, Byte>>();
        Capture _capture = new Capture(Filename);
        double totalFrames = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
        double fps = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
        double frameNumber = 0.0;

        bool Reading = true;

        while (Reading)
        {
            _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameNumber);
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
            if (frame != null)
            {
                //image_array.Add(frame.Copy());

                //frame.Save(OutFileLocation + "\\" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg");

                frame.Save(OutFileLocation + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                Reading = false;
            }

            frameNumber += (fps * TimeDiff);
        }

        return image_array;
}
```

If you want to crop the image to only include the captions, then you could just use an roi.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height / 4);
frame.ROI = rect;
```

Comment: i can capture all frame in video but i want only frame that including subtitle but i dont know which frame that including subtitle.. so i want program do it for me.......... one click collect all frame in video that including subtitle and extract to image... is it possible sir?

Comment: What you are talking about would be a mix of object/text detection and filtering. You would have to analyze each frame and detect the text. Try looking into blob detection within Emgucv. However, another option, but requires another algorithm in Python, would be Mask RCNN, which you could train a dataset on for text and then it could tell which frames there was text on.